# Simple function which has domain all real numbers and does not have derivation in point 0.

Tags: derivatives, definition, radicals

does $x^{1/3}$ have a derivative at $0$? I mean when we calculate it by definition, limits of both sides is $+\infty$ but I am not sure about conclusion, can anybody please explain it to me? thx a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is not differentiable at $0$ because asserting that a function $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$ means that the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists in $\mathbb R$. In your case, the limit exists, yes, but it is *not* a real number.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not, exactly as you said, the limit is undefined, hence it does not have a derivative

Comment: I am quite confused, because we defined derivation if limit exists, it means that if it is +infinity, derivation exists, but we can not construct any tangent line.

Comment: Could you give me another example of function which satisfies those criteria?

Comment: If the limit is $\infty$ then the limit does not exist, because $\infty$ is not a number. Another example is $\sqrt{x}$